# Catch browser offline event in IE and mozilla

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser, offline

I want to invoke the browser Online and Offline event. Below is what i tried.

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { console.log('offline'); });

window.addEventListener('online', function(e) { console.log('online'); });
```

The above code works for Google Chrome and safari, but for Firefox and Internet explorer its not working. The offline event is not triggering in Firefox and IE.

All the post that i have gone through uses navigation.online, but that is not working in IE, FF. Im looking for a cross browser solution for the same.

Comment: Just tested your code in Firefox and Edge, and it works as intended: turn off my connection, i get console logged "offline"...

Comment: ? Not sure i understand your request?

Comment: @Stuart, what i mean is, in FireFox and Internet Explorer, the online event is firing whereas the Offline event is not firing.

Comment: I see the offline event firing in both Firefox and Edge.